# Exclude for 60 days a contact from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Right now i'm creating a Journey. But i required that the contact don't entry again to this journey until 60 days pass and then they can entry again to the journey.

How can i accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: last wait step set to 60 days and re-entry only after exiting?

Answer (score 0):

In your journey, before Journey Exit, add a Wait period of 60 Days.

And the Journey Re-entry condition should be 'Re-Entry After Exit' only.

So, the contact will remain on the journey exit for 60 days and will be re-evaluated after exiting the journey.

Answer (score 0):

While the suggested Wait step solution may technically work, I believe there are more semantically correct alternatives for preventing contacts from re-entering a journey. Given the limited context provided, I propose the following solutions:

**Solution 1**: Utilize a 'hold Data Extension' by appending records that have entered the journey and their entry date. This way, you can filter out the records that have entered your journey in the last 60 days in your segmentation query. This solution allows you to easily identify and exclude recently entered contacts from the journey, making it more efficient and effective.

**Solution 2**: Create an automation that adds your contacts to an auto-suppression list for 60 days and apply it to the sender profile used in the email activities within the journey. This has the advantage of being able to be used across other journeys without having to modify your SQL queries or automations. It also ensures that contacts are automatically removed from the auto-suppression list after 60 days. However, it should be noted that this solution may affect your reporting data as contacts will still enter the journey but will be marked as "Not Sent."